# Slow first run with COM object

Tags: c#, .net, performance, com

I’m using a Photoshop COM object with late binding to communicate with Photoshop. But the first time I run my application it’s *very* slow! As a test I’ve removed the late binding and just used the following to instantiate new COM objects:

```
m_Application = new Photoshop.Application(); 
m_MakeActiveActionDescriptor = new Photoshop.ActionDescriptor();
```

First run it takes about 4500ms to go over all my layers, the second time it only takes about 1000ms.

I’ve read to ignore the first run of your application because of the CLR starting up, but users will probably only run my program once. ([C# object creation much slower than constructor call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717051/c-sharp-object-creation-much-slower-than-constructor-call), [Is CLR loaded and initialized everytime,when a new managed application is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245791/is-clr-loaded-and-initialized-everytime-when-a-new-managed-application-is-loaded)) I also don’t know if this really applies in this case because I’ve never seen such a slowdown the first run just from the CLR starting up.I’ve tried to profile my code and it looks like it’s the COM object slowing it down.

[image: First and second run profiler]

MakeActiveByIndex(), Initialize() and GetLayerType() all three of them work with COM objects and seem to be a lot slower the first run. Creating the COM objects is very fast, around 5-10ms, it seems that calling methods on them is the slow part. (InvokeMember, CreateInstanceSlow)

```
private void MakeActiveByIndex(int index, bool visible)
{
    var refe = new Photoshop.ActionReference(); //This needs to be a new object everytime I call this method. 
    refe.PutIndex(m_Application.CharIDToTypeID("Lyr "), index);
    m_MakeActiveActionDescriptor.PutReference(m_Application.CharIDToTypeID("null"), refe);
    m_MakeActiveActionDescriptor.PutBoolean(m_Application.CharIDToTypeID("MkVs"), visible);
    m_Application.ExecuteAction(m_Application.CharIDToTypeID("slct"), m_MakeActiveActionDescriptor, ps.PsDialogModes.psDisplayNoDialogs);
}
```

[image]

I’m running my app outside of VS in release mode.

Is there anything I can do to speed it up the first time? Thanks!

***EDIT:***

Normal for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    MakeActiveByIndex(groups[i], false, app);

    activeLayer = activeDocument.ActiveLayer;

    Console.WriteLine(activeLayer.Name);
}
```

Parallel for:

```
Parallel.For(0, groups.Count, i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    MakeActiveByIndex(groups[i], false, app);

    activeLayer = activeDocument.ActiveLayer;

    Console.WriteLine(activeLayer.Name);

});
```

Comment: Well,  doesn't the photoshop com object have to load/initialize the first time?  Some of the object's workload may be deferred until the first method is actually called on it. Can you start it in another thread on app startup?

Comment: Do the COM object and your app have the same threading model? That is, if the COM object is single-threaded then you should use it on an STA thread; if not it should still work though slowly. This may not make a difference to first and later executions though.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks! Do you mean the slowdown is normal? (I thought there would be a small slow down, but not this big) I forgot to mention in the original post that MakeActiveByIndex() is being called inside a for loop. I've never done any multi threading, so I'm not sure if my updated code makes any sense, I've replaced the normal for-loop with a  parallel.for-loop. This doesn't work though, I just get the same name back although the indices do change.

Comment: @groverboy Thanks! I’ll have to look into the “threading model” stuff because I have no idea what that means exactly… But are you saying that if my COM object is single threaded, that making it multi-threaded won’t make if faster at all regardless if it’s the first or later executions? (This would make sense I guess)

Comment: *Anything* you do for the first time is slow.  Just starting Photoshop takes a while, it is a large program.  They cover it up pretty well, splash screens and what-not, you'll have to do the same.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the advice! I may have focussed too much on performance time!

Comment: Using a single (aka 'apartment') threaded COM object on a multithreaded (MTA) thread should always be slower than using it on an STA thread. Note that .NET threadpool threads are MTA threaded.

Comment: @groverboy, this is an out-of-process COM object, that doesn't matter.  What would matter is if you're accessing the object from multiple threads simultaneously (STA or MTA threads in our process), but the server serializes the calls (STA in the server process, MTA in the server process where every method uses a lock).